# How to prevent writing in both TextField when I am writing in one TextField using this keypad?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I'm beginner in java and i stucked writing simple project using eclipse. I added numbered Buttons and they should be showed in TextField when user click them.
But when i'm trying to check this they add every number to both TextField.

How i can prevent this?

See Picture show it better:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtKhB.png]

```
private JFrame frame;
private final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
private final JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("1");
private final JButton btnNewButton_1_1 = new JButton("2");
private final JButton btnNewButton_1_2 = new JButton("3");
private final JButton btnNewButton_1_3 = new JButton("4");
private final JButton btnNewButton_1_1_1 = new JButton("5");
private final JButton btnNewButton_1_2_1 = new JButton("6");
private final JButton btnNewButton_1_4 = new JButton("7");
private final JButton btnNewButton_1_1_2 = new JButton("8");
private final JButton btnNewButton_1_2_2 = new JButton("9");
private final JButton btnNewButton_1_1_3 = new JButton("0");
private final JButton btnNewButton_1_2_4 = new JButton("Enter");
private final JButton btnNewButton_1_2_4_1 = new JButton("Cancel");
private final JButton btnNewButton_1_2_4_2 = new JButton("Clear");
private final JLabel lblNewLabel_4 = new JLabel("Welcome..!");
private final JLabel lblNewLabel_5 = new JLabel("Account Number:");
private final JLabel lblNewLabel_5_1 = new JLabel("PIN:");
private final JTextField textField = new JTextField();
private final JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField();
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(150, 10, 1000, 650);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(null);
    btnNewButton_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 23));
    btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String Enternumber1  = textField.getText()+btnNewButton_1.getText();
            textField.setText(Enternumber1);
            
            String Enternumber2  = passwordField.getText()+btnNewButton_1.getText();
            passwordField.setText(Enternumber2);
            
        }
```

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom `Action` that extends from `TextAction`. The `TextAction` allows you to track the last text component that had focus. You can then apply your keypad logic to this component:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class NumpadPanel extends JPanel
{
    public NumpadPanel()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        JTextField textField1 = new JTextField(4);
        JTextField textField2 = new JTextField(2);
        JTextField textField3 = new JTextField(2);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add( textField1 );
        panel.add( textField2 );
        panel.add( textField3 );
        add(panel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        Action numberAction = new TextAction("")
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                JTextComponent textComponent = getFocusedComponent();

                if (textComponent != null)
                    textComponent.replaceSelection(e.getActionCommand());
            }
        };

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout( new GridLayout(0, 5) );
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            String text = String.valueOf(i);
            JButton button = new JButton( text );
            button.addActionListener( numberAction );
            button.setMargin( new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20) );
            button.setFocusable( false );
            buttonPanel.add( button );
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Numpad Panel");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.add( new NumpadPanel() );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: it sees your answer stops in the middle of the sentence. Would you mind to complete what you were going to write?

Comment: @Felix Partial sentence removed.